# Why is the Opening of The Good Fight playing so late?

Tags: production, the-good-fight

I've been noticing in Season 2 of *The Good Fight* that the intro seems delayed. In I think Episode 7 of Season 2, the episode where at the end

> Maia hocks up with that assistant for the DMC in the meeting room the Department of Justice set up the camera's in

the opening didn't occur for 17 minutes into the episode and that's only going off the scheduled start time and the current time (it may have started sooner or later than the time)

I watch a lot of anime and other TV series and I've never seen an Opening be delayed that long. Instances where it has generally at the start of a series that the opening credits are overlayed as the episode starts proper and the Opening is played as an Ending.

But that's not the case here and even if they didn't want to break up the flow of the story at the start they could have done the opening as the first thing.

So why is the Opening of The Good Fight playing so late?

NOTE: this is on Australian Free-to-Air Television on SBS

Comment: Haven't seen this series yet, but it is a spin-off from The Good Wife, and on that show the title sequence did tend to move to much later in the episode in later years.

Comment: Most of Robert & Michelle King's co-productions with Ridley Scott now do this. Sometimes the sequences are early, but sometimes they won't appear until up to 19 mins in. There's also a special TGF episode 5.01 that has the opening credit at the very end of the episode, as that episode is "acting like" a "previously on" episode where they catch up with the characters through the beginning of the Pandemic & where 2 main cast members were leaving the show. For The Good Fight in particular these stylistic choices play into the nature of the series. Evil is also right in line with TGF...